# Replicating a Tweedie corrected experiment from Computer Age Statistical Inference

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, splines, tweedie-distribution, empirical-bayes

I have been attempting to replicate an experiment from [Computer Age Statistical Inference](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/PDF/casi.pdf) by Bradley Efron and Trevor Hastie on page 411.

In this experiment 100 datasets are populated normal random values. These values are then then corrected by subtracting from Tweedie's estimates. In the book the following plot is produced.

[image]

I made an attempt to replicate this experiment, but I believe my Tweedie estimates are wrong.

I was hoping someone could point out my error.

## Code

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(statmod)
require(splines)

make_z <- function(){
  # mu is e^{-mu} distributed where (mu > 0)
  u <- -rexp(n = 1000)
  z <- rnorm(u)
  tibble(z, u)
}

get_tweedie <- function(data){
  z <- data$z
  u <- data$u
  # Get Tweedie's estimate using a natrual spline model with 5 degrees of freedom
  fit <- glm(z ~ ns(u, 5), data = data, family=tweedie(var.power=0, link.power=1L))
  exp(predict(fit, type = "response"))
}

df_z <- tibble(dataset = seq(1:100)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Z = list(make_z())) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(tweedie = map(Z, get_tweedie)) %>% 
  unnest(c(Z, tweedie)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(u)) %>% 
  group_by(dataset) %>% 
  # For each dataset, the 20 largest z values and the corresponding tweedie
  # estimates and actual mu values were recorded
  top_n(20, z) %>% 
  # uncorrected and corrected differences were calculated. The hope being
  # that empirical Bayes shrinkage would correct the selection bais in the
  # z values.
  mutate(uncorr = z - u,
         corrected = tweedie - u)

# ggplot
df_z %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(uncorr, corrected) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = key)) +
  geom_histogram(color = "white", bins = 45) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

## Experiment

I am putting the experiment details here for convenience.

[image]

Comment: I am the author of the `statmod::tweedie` function used in your code. I think you might be confusing different statistical methods attributed to Tweedie. *Tweedie's formula* used in Efron & Hastie (2016) actually has nothing to do with *Tweedie distributions* or with Tweedie glms. Given the settings for `var.power` and `link.power`, your code line using `tweedie` is actually the same as `fit <- glm(z ~ ns(u, 5), data = df_1, family=gaussian())`.

Comment: ... so you're actually just fitting an ordinary linear model by least squares. You may as well have used `lm`. You are not doing any bias correction as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize the distinction. Would you have any insight on how I can calculate _Tweedie's formula_ in this situation? All descriptions I have found in the book are analytical formulas for $\hat{\mu_i} = z_i + \hat{l}'(z_i)$. I have not been able to find any code that estimates this value.

Comment: That's because there isn't any code. Efron & Hastie's book is about research methods that are not implemented in standard public code packages. BTW, another problem with your code is that you have not generated the `u` from an exponential distribution. Any reason why you wouldn't use `rexp`?

Comment: I should have used `rexp` thanks for pointing that out.